# Optimal Strategy for Chosing Lottery Tickets

Tags: probability, optimization

You have 2 types of lottery tickets: one that costs $c_1$ and has a probability of winning of $p_1$, and the other costs $c_2$ and has a probability of winning of $p_2$. The goal, as you might expect, is to win by spending the least money. You play until you win it.

Here the optimal strategy is to pick whichever ticket has $c/p$ lower. The reasoning behind is that $c/p$ is the expected cost or each ticket (geometric distribution).

Now consider the following twist: every time you make a pick (1 or 2), two new types of tickets are created, with arbitrary $c$ and $p$.

Intuitively, I would say the optimal strategy remains the same: pick whichever has lower $c/p$. But I fail to find a convincing mathematical argument.

Comment: I think you mean lowest c/p at the end.

Comment: what do you know about distribution of $c$ and $p$? nothing?

Comment: Well? Are you happy with my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your problem is ambiguous, every go, can you only buy the new ticket type or can you buy old or new?

Anyway, this does not matter.

Your conujecture is wrong:

without knowing the distribution of future $c_i$ and $p_i$, it is unclear what the optimal solution is. here is an example

Let $c_1= 100$ $p_1=1$ and $c_2 = 1$ and $p=0.00001$, then according to your strategy,  then you buy ticket 1.

However, if you know two new tickets are created, let one of ticket created will be $c_3 = 1$ $p_3=1$, the optimal strategy might be to buy ticket 2 followed by 3, the maximum cost possible is 2, comparing to 100 if you buy ticket 1 on turn 1.

A problem with similar favour:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/153006/partially-observable-markov-decision-process-finding-a-hidden-object-with-some

It is very hard to solve this type of problem explicitly. In my example, the optimal policy is unknown though simulation agrees with the conjecture. In your case, i do not think the conjecture is 'not usually' correct because we often want to 'wait for a better deal' if the cost is very very low.

Comment: I thought this right away too.  To say it in simpler terms, the strategy may be to buy the cheapest ticket possible, waiting for a good deal to come up.  The trick is how to represent this mathematically.

Comment: @Lost1,Andrey: good point, it is true that with no information on the subsequent deals, something like this might come up. I probably need to rethink my question. Should I update this post ?

Comment: @doc i think you can ask another question but i can tell you that your conjecture may still be false, because you can easily modify my example just by letting a c_3 occur with a high probability. This sort of problem is called Markov decision process. There is a vast amount of literature in this area but many problem do not have explicit solutions. Let me link you to a question i asked, the flavour is very similar to this question

Comment: @Andrey formulating this problem in the language of optimal control is very easy, solving it is impossible, unless we appeal to computation techniques.

Comment: @Lost1: I understand your concern, but the thing is that I may have been overly liberate with the assumptions. In fact I do know something about future $c$ and $p$, I just thought initially that it did not matter. Obviously, it does.

Comment: @doc even if we think it is correct, it would be very hard to verify the conjecture! See the new link in my post, and i personally don't it usually is. If you take c and p to be independently, uniformly distributed with on (0,1), i think you might still be able to find a counterexample, similar to mine in question for certain value of c and p.

Comment: @Lost1: It's not just the distribution. In fact I think (still working it out) that we could formulate it this way: the cost always remains the same, and each time you choose ticket A, the next ticket A will have its probability multiplied by a constant factor $k_A<1$, and ticket B remains the same (and vice-versa). But it might be more or less complicated, I need to think about it a bit more. At any rate, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @doc sure then formulate it another post. Fixing cost is a massive simplification!